# Templated Defaulted default constructor

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I would like to have the definition of the default constructor be switched at compile time by a template parameter.  I can get this to compile OK for a conversion constructor, but trying to use that method for a default constructor to be defaulted or not--useful if in the case of particular template parameter, the resulting class could be POD, but in another case, it could not--but I get a compiler error when doing so.  Short of specializing the template and duplicating all the code that's the same, is there a way to do this?  Here's a simplified version of what I was trying:

```
#include<type_traits>   // for enable_if

template <bool MyParameter>
class Demonstration
{
    public:

        //trivial copy, move constructors/assignment, and trivial destructor
        constexpr Demonstration(Demonstration const &) = default;
        constexpr Demonstration(Demonstration &&) = default;
        Demonstration & operator= (Demonstration const &) = default;
        Demonstration & operator= (Demonstration &&) = default;
        ~Demonstration() = default;

        // this one gives "error: a template cannot be defauled"
        template <bool Dummy=MyParameter, typename std::enable_if< Dummy , bool >::type=true >
        Demonstration() = default;

        // ok
        template <bool Dummy=MyParameter, typename std::enable_if< !Dummy , bool >::type=false >
        Demonstration() : myValue(0) {}

        // ok
        template <bool Dummy=MyParameter, typename std::enable_if< Dummy , bool >::type=true >
        explicit constexpr Demonstration(unsigned char toConvert)
        : myValue ( toConvert )
        {
        }
        // ok
        template <bool Dummy=MyParameter, typename std::enable_if< !Dummy , bool >::type=false >
        explicit constexpr Demonstration(unsigned char toConvert)
        : myValue ( toConvert > 100 ? 0 : toConvert )
        {
        }

    // a lot of functions that do not depend on parameter go here

    protected:
    private:
        unsigned char myValue;

};
```

Comment: Even if this compiled, `Demonstration<true>` would technically still not be POD.  "A _trivial class_ is a class that has a default constructor, has no non-trivial default constructors, and is trivially copyable."  `Demonstration<true>` has two default constructors and one is non-trivial, even though it can never be a viable function for overload resolution.

Comment: CRTP implement the duplicate functions, and have the ctors be in two specializations?

Comment: You can't use template default constructor because you can't explicitly specify its template arguments. You can only create template constructors with parameters which would allow compiler to deduce its template arguments. You can try to achieve what you want with template static function which returns constructed object of `Demonstration` class.

Comment: Thanks all of you, that clears up my confusion.  @Yakk: CRTP does look to be the way to achieve having the class be POD or non-POD based on a template parameter without lots of duplication; if you submit that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @signifyingnothing naw, just self answer: I cannot be bothered to write up a good one right now.  And a bad answer is not worth writing.

Answer (score 1):

GCC complains of your template:

```
error: a template cannot be defaulted
```

and Clang complains:

```
error: only special member functions may be defaulted.
```

That seems fair enough. A member function template is not a member function,
let alone a special one.

You would like `Demonstration<bool P>` to be POD when `P` is true and otherwise
not necessarily so.

A possible solution is to delegate the parameterization of POD-ness entirely
to specializations of a base template `base<bool P>` and have 
`Demonstration<P>` inherit `base<P>`. Here is an illustration:

```
#include<type_traits>

template<bool Param = true>
struct base // is POD 
{
    base() = default;
    explicit constexpr base(unsigned char ch)
    : _val(ch){}
    unsigned char _val;
};

template<>
struct base<false> // is not POD
{
    base() = default;
    explicit constexpr base(unsigned char ch)
    : _val(ch > 100 ? 0 : ch){}
    unsigned char _val = 0;
};


template <bool MyParameter>
class Demonstration : private base<MyParameter>
{   
public:

    Demonstration() = default;
    //trivial copy, move constructors/assignment, and trivial destructor
    constexpr Demonstration(Demonstration const &) = default;
    constexpr Demonstration(Demonstration &&) = default;
    Demonstration & operator= (Demonstration const &) = default;
    Demonstration & operator= (Demonstration &&) = default;
    ~Demonstration() = default;

    explicit constexpr Demonstration(unsigned char toConvert)
    : base<MyParameter>(toConvert)
    {
    }

    char myValue() const {
        return base<MyParameter>::_val;
    }
};


#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "is_pod<base<true>>::value = " 
        << is_pod<Demonstration<true>>::value << endl;
    cout << "is_pod<base<false>>::value = " 
        << is_pod<Demonstration<false>>::value << endl;
    cout << "is_pod<Demonstration<true>>::value = " 
        << is_pod<Demonstration<true>>::value << endl;
    cout << "is_pod<Demonstration<false>>::value = " 
        << is_pod<Demonstration<false>>::value << endl;
    Demonstration<true> d_true(1);
    Demonstration<false> d_false(101);
    std::cout << "(int)Demonstration<true>(1).myValue() = " 
        << (int)d_true.myValue() << endl;
    std::cout << "(int)Demonstration<false>(101).myValue() = " 
        << (int)d_false.myValue() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now `Demonstration<P>` is POD just in case `base<P>` is POD. The program
outputs:

```
is_pod<base<true>>::value = 1
is_pod<base<false>>::value = 0
is_pod<Demonstration<true>>::value = 1
is_pod<Demonstration<false>>::value = 0
(int)Demonstration<true>(1).myValue() = 1
(int)Demonstration<false>(101).myValue() = 0
```

Built with GCC 4.8.2 and clang 3.3